# problem with curl piping $_POST and $_FILES in same request

Tags: php, http, curl

I'm trying to recreate an entire http request including both post and files data however no matter what I do I can't seem to get my files to work, the code I'm using is below...

```
$count=count($_FILES['photographs']['tmp_name']);

$file_posts=array();

for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {
    if(!empty($_FILES['photographs']['name'][$i])) {    
 $_FILES['photographs']['tmp_name'][$i] = "@".$_FILES['photographs']['tmp_name'][$i];
    }
}

$post = array_merge($_POST, $_FILES);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"http://url/to/file.php");      
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I've tried many variants of this but I can't seem to get files to work no matter what, other post data is fine however.

Comment: Do you need to do something after the request? If not, why don't you just reverse proxy the request? Otherwise, show us how the `$post` variable looks like in the end -- my guess is doesn't look good.

Comment: Array ( [stocknum] => ABC123 [make] => MAKE [model] => MODEL [price] => [year] => 2002 [bodytype] => Sedan [transmission] => 6sp Manual [grade] => [klms] => [drivetype] => [fueltype] => PETROL [chassistype] => SEDAN [engine] => [colour] => [interiorcolour] => [shortdescription] => [longdescription] => [keywords] => [availability] => Available [add_vehicle] => Add Vehicle [photographs] => Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => Winter.jpg [1] => Water lilies.jpg [2] => Sunset.jpg [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => [8] => [9] => [10] => [11] => [12] => [13] => 

etc

Comment: 15] => ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => @/tmp/phpwxNJqG [1] => @/tmp/phpAsDVvN [2] => @/tmp/phpsf8BJX [3] => [4] =

Comment: The file the request is destined for is setup to process in this format...as far as I knew the only requirement for files over curl is putting an @ in front of the tmp name

Comment: @Artefacto I'm not quite sure what you mean by running a reverse proxy, can you explain a little?

Comment: @Toby Something like `RewriteRule ^here\.php$ http://url/to/there.php [P]`. This needs mod_proxy enabled though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there is a second 'layer' of arrays in your `$post`.

You need to do:

```
$file_posts=array();

for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {
    if(!empty($_FILES['photographs']['name'][$i])) {    
       $file_posts['photographs'][$i] = "@".$_FILES['photographs']['tmp_name'][$i];
    }
}
```